# How to avoid nesting promises with $q

Tags: javascript, q, angular-promise

I am trying to get more into promises and less into async. I have:

```
var findRepositoryPromise, getUserTeamsPromise;

getUserTeamsPromise = null;

findRepositoryPromise = RepositoryService.find($stateParams.host, $stateParams.owner, $stateParams.repository);

findRepositoryPromise.then(function(response) {
  $scope.selectedRepository = response.repository;
  getUserTeamsPromise = TeamService.getUserTeams($rootScope.user.id);
  return getUserTeamsPromise.then(function(response) {
    $scope.teams = response.teams;
    $scope.selectedTeam = $scope.teams[0];
    $scope.selectedTeamId = $scope.selectedTeam.id;
    return $scope.getTeamRepositories($scope.selectedTeamId);
  });
});

findRepositoryPromise.catch(function(error) {
  return toaster.pop('error', 'Error', error);
});
```

I think I have the `findRepositoryPromise` part down right by separating the `then` and the `catch`. But I still have the `getUserTeamsPromise` nested. This seems somehow wrong. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

caveat - I am more familiar with the Promises implementation in the "promise" npm module, but if q works the same way, you can do this:

```
var findRepositoryPromise;

findRepositoryPromise = RepositoryService.find($stateParams.host, $stateParams.owner, $stateParams.repository);

findRepositoryPromise.then(function(response) {
      $scope.selectedRepository = response.repository;
      return TeamService.getUserTeams($rootScope.user.id);
}).then(function(response) {
    $scope.teams = response.teams;
    $scope.selectedTeam = $scope.teams[0];
    $scope.selectedTeamId = $scope.selectedTeam.id;
    return $scope.getTeamRepositories($scope.selectedTeamId);
});

findRepositoryPromise.catch(function(error) {
  return toaster.pop('error', 'Error', error);
});
```

Because the promise will take over the state of the return value of its then callback - and if this is a promise, it can be chained as shown above. This also means that if `return $scope.getTeamRepositories($scope.selectedTeamId);` is also returning a promise, its result can be retrieved in another chained `.then` call.